# Angular2 Routing Path-Style Parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Using the `@angular/router` version `3.0.0-beta.2` I would like to build an application which allows my users to browse a filesystem.

The following illustrates the types of URL I would like to support:

```
http://myapp/browse                   <--- Browse without parameters, lists root dir
http://myapp/browse/animals           <--- Browse "animals" subdirectory
http://myapp/browse/animals/mammals   <--- Browse "animals/mammals" subdirectory
```

I am struggling to come up with a mechanism to configure this using `RouterConfig`.

---

### Path-style Parameters

```
{ path: 'browse/:path', component: BrowserComponent }
```

This `RouterConfig` only supports a single subdirectory, i.e. `browse/animals`. However, if I attempt to browse to the second-level of subdirectory `/browse/animals/mammals` I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes: '/browse/animals/mammals'
```

I understand that the default behaviour of a parameter in the router (in this case `:path`) is to "break" on the first forward slash, and assume the following token is a sub-path.

How can I configure the router to allow the `:path` parameter to accept forward slashes / "gobble" the entire remaining URL as the parameter?

---

### Optional Parameter

How can I deal with the use-case where the user wishes to browse the root directory, i.e. the URL `/browse`. This will not match the router configuration described above, as the `:path` parameter is not present.

I have attempted to work around this using two distinctly configured router paths:

```
{ path: 'browse', component: BrowserComponent },
{ path: 'browse/:path', component: BrowserComponent }
```

However, this is causing me problems with `routerLinkActive`. I have a main menu with a link to the browser, that looks like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/browse']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">...</a>
```

I would like this main menu link to have the `active` class if the user has browsed to the root `/browse` or to some subdirectory `/browse/animals/`.

However, given the `/browse/animals/` URL is not a child of the `/browse` route, it does not become `active`.

I cannot make the `:path` parameter route a child of the `/browse` root, as there is no need for a nested view, and it results in:

```
Cannot find primary outlet to load BrowserComponent
```

Comment: Any reason you don't use version beta.2 of the router? I wouldn't expect this to work but several other issues were fixed.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer No, there's no good reason I'm not using that version of the router. I'll bump forward my dependency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building on the `**` suggestion from @DaSch, it is indeed possible to use the wildcard route:

```
{ path: '/browse', component: BrowserComponent, children: [ { path: '**' } ] }
```

There is no need to have a nested `router-outlet` within the `BrowserComponent` as there is no `component` field specified on the child path.

As desired, the BrowserComponent will now be routed for all the described URLs:

```
http://myapp/browse
http://myapp/browse/animals
http://myapp/browse/animals/mammals
```

The challenge now is to obtain the par tof the URL which represents the path that the browser has navigated to, and subscribe to changes as the user navigates.

I have prototyped this using the `Router`:

```
router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .forEach((event: NavigationEnd) => {

    // The root route belongs to "/browse"
    let parentRoot: ActivatedRoute = router.routerState.root.firstChild;
    if (parentRoot.snapshot.url.map(p => p.path).join("/") == "/browse") {

      let path: string = "";

      // Child route is optional, in case the user has browsed to just "/browse"
      let childRoute: ActivatedRoute = parentRoot.firstChild;
      if (childRoute) {
        path = childRoute.snapshot.url.map(p => p.path).join("/");
        console.log("New browser path is ", path);
      }

      this.loadPath(path);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Good to know, nice!

Comment: @jwa hi, I am using your code sample. It's really perfect. Thank you. I want to ask you a question about it. I use this method in my shared component. And I use it in multiple components as you guess. Like: /browse, /deleted, /shared etc. When I click another route (using shared component), this.router.events.observers length is increasing. When I click completely different route (/foo which isn't have shared component), It resets itself (normally this.router.events.observers length is 17). How can I prevent increasing observer array's length when I go another route which has shared component?

Comment: @jwa ok I solved it with subscription. Could you please check if it's true?


`this.routerSubscription = router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                console.log('bbb');
            }
        });

ngOnDestroy() {
        this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }`

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone: in Angular 4.1.x, I used `component` in the wildcard child rather than the parent: `{path: 'browse', children: [{path: '**', component: BrowserComponent}]}`. I liked your version slightly better, but after changing it I ran into _"Invalid configuration of route 'browse/**'. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren"_. As my previous version worked just fine for me too, I reverted my change and did not investigate...

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried this, but from the documentation, I would try to use children with a wildcard selector.

```
{ path: 'browse', 
  component: ...,
  children: [
     path: '**',
     component: ...
]},
```

It's just guess and I would have to check how to retrieve the path parameters to get the right content for the given path.

Comment: That won't work. First you dont have an router-outlet in this component and if you would add one, the component would be rendered again in our component.

Comment: Well, that you might need two different components. That's details It's just about using wildcards in children path.

Comment: @mxii - Having prototyped this I can confirm that you would *NOT* need a new outlet. The additional outlet is only required if a component is specified.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way..

Just using your first route: `{ path: 'browse', component: BrowserComponent }`

And for the folder names using so called `optional routes`.

The link should have this syntax here:

`<a [routerLink]="['/browse', ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4'] ]">--link name--</a>`

or like this:

`<a [routerLink]="['/browse', { folders: ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4'] } ]">--link name--</a>`

Inject `private _route: ActivatedRoute` to your Component's constructor and subscribe to the params:

```
this._route.params.subscribe(
      val => console.log(val),
      err => console.log(err));
```

The first will print this: `Object {0: "f1", 1: "f2", 2: "f3", 3: "f4"}`
and the second will print this: `Object {folders: "f1,f2,f3,f4"}`

Or maybe you will get another idea to add your folders using this `optional parameters`.. gl! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can configure the router dynamically like explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38096260/217408

```
router.resetConfig([
 { path: 'team/:id', component: TeamCmp, children: [
   { path: 'simple', component: SimpleCmp },
   { path: 'user/:name', component: UserCmp }
 ] }
]);
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11437#issuecomment-245995186 provides an **RC.6** Plunker

Comment: In my understanding that's not the real problem. If I understand him right, the route itself is just "/browse" and he has only this component, but he wants to put the arguments in this style URL/browse/folder1/folder2/folder3/..../folderN. and this is not possible (if i am right) ..

Comment: But he can reconfigure a router to support more parameters or add child routes to get this behavior. I think using `router.resetConfig` is a valid approach.

Answer (score -1):

Can useful, for me good worked `router.resetConfig()` with new route rules in custom logic of my app