# Dynamically loading components in Angular2 RC.5

Tags: angular

Considering the new changes that came out with the new RC I'm a bit lost at how I should approach this problem.

I have a .json file containing the name and path for the components I want to dinamically load. I can change the structure of this file if needed :

Example:

```
[
  {"component": "Comp1", "path": "./comp1.js"},
  {"component": "Comp2", "path": "./comp2.js"}
]
```

Until now I've used to load the JSON, System import the js files, save them in an array and simply reset the router config. Here's a really old and outdated version but the principle is the same: http://embed.plnkr.co/jAmMZKz2VqponmFtPpes/

I'm also interested in having those components lazy load. No clue on how to do that yet.

Now the ideas that came to my mind on how I could do this:

1. Get the json before bootstraping and pass it to the router. Would prefer not doing this since it isn't really "the angular2 way".
2. Doing a `LoadNextToContent` every time the user requires a dynamically loaded component and removing it when he is done using it.

Are there easier ways to do this? Better ways performance wise?

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/38096260/217408

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, I asked that question too. I used it and it works perfectly with RC.4. Thing is with Rc5 you need to add them to the entryComponents and it turns out to be a pain. Feels like there should be an easier way I'm totally missing.

Comment: I see. Didn't investigate this topic with RC.5 yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about ng2 rc 5, then NgModule has been introduced and that just like angularj 1 module concept. remember you are loading module, not components
Set up rootModule as:

```
  import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
  import { routing }        from './app.routing';
  @NgModule({
     imports:      [ BrowserModule,HttpModule,JsonpModule, routing ],
     declarations: [ AppComponent ],
     bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
 export class AppModule { }
```

And inside  Inside ./app.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes= GetScreens();
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
function GetScreens(){
var results :Array<Object> = Array<Object>();
let screens :Array<string> = ["page1","page2","page3"]

results.push({ path: '' ,redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full'});
results.push({ path: 'welcome', loadChildren: 'app/screens/welcome.module' })
screens.map(screenId => results.push({path: screenId, loadChildren: 'app/screens/' + screenId + '.module' }))
return results 
}
```

Adn finally here  you want :{ path: 'welcome', loadChildren: 'app/screens/welcome.module' }.

"ap/screens/welcom.module.ts" is a file on you disk.

```
let screens :Array<string> = ["page1","page2","page3"]
```

here array for screen names can be read from json call.
in http://plnkr.co/edit/nm5m7N?p=preview you can find full details above and check app/MyRouterLinks.ts, it calls and gets json file to load component.
Or see source code: https://github.com/Longfld/DynamicalRouter

Comment: The idea sounds good. Two questions arise however: 1. If the JSON is large, can I use a promise? and 2. If I want to change the routes/components during run-time, how?

Comment: Promise?  Yes you can but observable is far more better way to use,  if I have option I won't back to promise.   I thought I've show you how to load routes/components during run-time.  Not should what u mean by "to change....  during run-time"